# Dynamics of interconnected rigid bodies using Newtonian physics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

Passive SONAR uses a towed array system to hear the underwater sound uninterrupted. This towed array sonar is a system of hydrophones towed behind a submarine or a surface ship on a cable. The cylindrical cable is hinged to the ship, and the cylindrical array sensor is hinged to that cable. I am designing the dynamics of this tow-cable based on the ship's motion. So, I want to know the dynamical equation that exists between towed cable and towed array, which is basically the dynamics of interconnected bodies.
The dynamical equation will include how the motion of the 3rd body will affect the motion of the 2nd body. [![enter image description here] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsLGO.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsLGO.png)
[image: Planar motion of 3 interconnected bodies in 2D]
Here im dealing with the problem of three interconnected rigid cylindrical bodies hinged at points A and B, where both the cylindrical bodies can move freely in 2D plane. The path of the surface vessel is always known to the user, so the position , velocity, and acceleration of point A are known at all time instants. I need help to formulate the kinematic and dynamic equations relating the cylindrical body motions in the xy-plane.

Comment: Is it, as the picture makes it look, simply one long series of things connected in a row?  Need more details on the shape of the towed components and the motion of the ship that will be considered.

Comment: @Dan The cylindrical bodies 1 and 2 are interconnected (hinged) like any sensor array hinged to rope. They are free to move in XY plane. Motion of ship is always known to the user, such that the position coordinates, velocity and acceleration of point A in XY plane are always available to us. I want to know how the dynamical and kinematical equation of cylindrical bodies will be related, especially during the manoeuvring period

Comment: @rohitkumarsingh My preference for this kind of problem would be Lagrangian mechanics approach, in order to capture "easily" all the interactions between the bodies. I would probably make some simplifying abstractions to model this problem as a pure mechanics problem and would consider the ship as a mass-point whose time-trajectory is given and would model the cable and the array as rigid one dimensional segments (if I have understood your description correctly). Then would introduce appropriate polar coordinates to use for the Lagrangian description. Are you still interested in this model?

Comment: @Futurologist Pardon me for the delay in replying. I thought of similar modeling as you have mentioned for ship and tow. But can't come up with the Lagrangian mechanics part. If you can help me out in Lagrangian Modeling, then it shall be very helpful.